# Android - error while try connect to local server(Xampp)

Tags: android, xampp

here's my logcat and the first line the url i try to connect with and it's valid url

[image: here's my logcat and the first line the url i try to connect with and it's valid url]

her is my code that cause the error and make the connection to refuse

```
public static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
    String jsonResponse = "";
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, url.toString());

    // If the URL is null, then return early.
    if (url == null) {
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // If the request was successful (response code 200),
        // then read the input stream and parse the response.
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the Category JSON results.", e);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

i already know how to make Http connect and done it a lot before but this the first time on local server

Comment: Is the server on the device? No? Then why are you using localhost? Asked bazillion times...

Comment: yes the server on the laptop and i run app on emulator  @Selvin

Comment: On emulator localhost is obviously emulator not emulator's host. Feel free to search similar questions for the answer.

Comment: i'm the host and i run it my emulator!! what's the wrong

Comment: Emulator's host is your pc not you. Again, on emulator localhost is emulator not emulator's host... Do you understand english?

Comment: @KarimAta What is the localhost port you are targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since local host for Emulator and Laptop is different, you need to do following:

1. Get the IP address of your PC using: `ipconfig` command in your Laptop's command prompt.
2. Instead of using `localhost`, you should use `ipAddress` in your URL.

So your address will become:
`http://<ip address>/lotus/getstats.php?category=ATM`