# Accessing localhost server and internet in android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, android-studio-2.3

How to access localhost server and internet in android emulator ?

I am behind my company proxy, to access the internet I have added the proxy host and port in emulators APN settings. I can able to access the internet, however this setting prevents me from accessing my localhost server since it couldn't able to recognise my machines IP address.

Can anyone help me out with the correct settings/workaround to achieve both internet access and local host development server from Android emulator?

P.S : I am developing an react native application

Edit:

Since I need internet access in my emulator to use Google maps I have added proxy to APN settings in emulator. After adding that I can't access my local development service using machine ip. It's not getting recognised.

Hope my edit gives some clarity on what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Use your machine IP address instead of localhost.

If you are on windows : `ipconfig`

If you are on linux : `ifconfig`

And then take the ipv4 value to connect to your databasen, not localhost. Should work if you are, like you said, inside your company network and if the server is also in this network

**EDIT :**

You can also try to create a [Local Tunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel) if you are running a nodejs server or an equivalent.

> localtunnel exposes your localhost to the world for easy testing and sharing! No need to mess with DNS or deploy just to have others test out your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost for emulator is different from localhost for PC.

Since your emulator and PC are in same network, instead of using localhost, use IP address of your PC. This will result in achieving your intended behavior.
You can check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786287/android-error-while-try-connect-to-local-serverxampp/49786809#49786809) for how to achieve it.

Comment: Yes I know that localhost from an emulator denotes the emulator itself . Previously(before adding the proxy in APN settings in emulator) I accessed my local server using my machine up only .. however since I need internet to access Google maps I have added proxy in my emulator APN settings .  After that localhost is not recognised by my proxy (which is obvious) so I need a way to achieve both.   Hope you got my point !!